# Prove that functions are one-to-one

Tags: functions, proof-writing, proof-verification

Given $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = x^{3}$

Proof: Assume $f(m)=f(n)$ for some $m, n \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $m^{3}=n^{3}$, and $m=n$. $f$ is one-to-one.

Given $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = 2^{x}$

Proof: $f'(x) = \ln(2) \times 2^{x} \neq 0$, so by Rolle's theorem, $f$ is one-to-one.

Are my proofs valid?

Comment: Are you using Rolle's theorem to show that the function is strictly monotone and thus injective?

Comment: For the first part, I think you should say something about _why_ $m=n$ follows from $m^3 = n^3$, because that is the whole point of the problem.  From what you have said, it is not clear why the argument works when $f(x)=x^3$ and not when $f(x) = x^2$, say.

Comment: If you use the Rolle's theorem I know, it means that you argue by contradiction. So you miss one sentence or two. For the first exercise, you have not proved anything, as Trevor Wilson already said. And the argument depends on the tools you have at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is fine, but you need to add why you we can conclude, from the fact that $x^3 = y^3$, it necessarily follows that $x = y$.

For the second, I'd suggest elaborating on (stating explicitly) how you think Rolle's Theorem applies and what the derivative tells you about this function. It works, but I think it's important for you to explain why and how it leads to the conclusion that $f(x)$ is one-to-one.